# Is there a way to implement fs in html script?

Tags: electron

I am trying to start a music player. For that I created a json-file that describes the path where the songs are located. Also the amount of songs that I have and the author.

```
    {
      "songs":[
        {
          "author": "Guns and Roses",
          "name": "Welcome to the Jungle",
          "url": "./Resources/welcome-to-the-jungle.mp3"
        }
        ]
    }
```

I am building this application in electron. In the html-file I have added one script with the name 'functions.js'.

`<script type="module" src="functions.js"></script>`

In that function I wanted to import the module fs and read my json-file to start working. But I am missing something. I get a message error that says I can't import the fs-module.

```
import fs from 'fs' 
const file = fs.readFileSync('./Resources/metadata.json')
```

I tried also,

```
import fs from '../node_modules/fs' 
const file = fs.readFileSync('./Resources/metadata.json')
```

and also add a script to the html file index.js

```
<script src="fs.js"></script>
```

But nothing works... what is the correct way to import the library into my script?

Comment: Why you don't read the file using Fetch or Axios!?
is the purpose of your question to read the file or to use fs!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import it with `require`

```js
const fs = require('fs')
```

If it throws the error saying `require is not defined`, enable node integration in your main process, this will allow your window to use Node's `require` function:

```js
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  ...
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true
  }
})
```